# Duplicated form after double click into the DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So, I will try to explain what I want my application to do:

1) In the Main Form I have a `TextBox` and a `DataGridView`. I will insert into the `TextBox` what I want to search and then click `F1` to open the Second Form which will display in another `DataGridView`.

2) I will double click into the Second Form `DataGridView` and that column value will be displayed into the `TextBox` from the Main Form.

3) After it, that `TextBox` is filled and depending on that value it will insert into the Main Form `DataGridView` that value detailed.

In the **Second Form** `DataGridView` I have the double click event with this:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        this.Hide();

        frmPrincipal frm = new frmPrincipal();

        frm.Show();

        frm.txtCarga.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        frm.txtCarga.Focus();
        frm.txtCarga.SelectAll();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

This is when I call the Second Form in the Principal Form:

```
private void txtCarga_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
            {
                this.Hide();
                frmPesquisa frmP = new frmPesquisa();
                frmP.Show();
                con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConnP);
                con.Open();

                string querySelect = @"SELECT CL.Cargs
                                    FROM CargsCab CC (NOLOCK)
                                    INNER JOIN CargsLin CL (NOLOCK) ON CC.Cargs = CL.Cargs
                                    INNER JOIN Stock S (NOLOCK) ON CL.Code = S.Code
                                    WHERE CC.Date >= GETDATE() - 120 AND CL.State NOT IN ('F', 'A') AND S.Type = 'P' 
                                    AND CC.TypeB = 'OCS' AND CL.Cargs LIKE '%" + txtCargs.Text + "%' GROUP BY CL.Cargs ORDER BY CL.Cargs DESC";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(querySelect);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cargs", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "CL.Cargs"));
                cmd.Parameters["@Cargs"].Value = txtCargs.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "CargsCab");

                frmP.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["CargsCab"].DefaultView;

                txtCarga.SelectAll();

                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

The issue here is that if I use the `frm.Show();` it will open a new frmPrincipal form, but I already have one. If I comment the `frm.Show();` the code will not be executed, but no erros displays. Basically that value will not be displayed into the `TextBox`.

What should I do?

Comment: You are creating a new form in your method. Put your frm variable into your class as a static variable. Only create it if it's null the first time

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my answer based on your new edits

```
public class frmPrincipal
{
    // ....
    // rest of your form Code

    private void txtCarga_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            frmPesquisa frmP = new frmPesquisa(this); // Pass a reference to this form
            frmP.Show();
            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConnP);
            con.Open();

            string querySelect = @"SELECT CL.Cargs
                                FROM CargsCab CC (NOLOCK)
                                INNER JOIN CargsLin CL (NOLOCK) ON CC.Cargs = CL.Cargs
                                INNER JOIN Stock S (NOLOCK) ON CL.Code = S.Code
                                WHERE CC.Date >= GETDATE() - 120 AND CL.State NOT IN ('F', 'A') AND S.Type = 'P' 
                                AND CC.TypeB = 'OCS' AND CL.Cargs LIKE '%" + txtCargs.Text + "%' GROUP BY CL.Cargs ORDER BY CL.Cargs DESC";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(querySelect);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cargs", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "CL.Cargs"));
            cmd.Parameters["@Cargs"].Value = txtCargs.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "CargsCab");

            frmP.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["CargsCab"].DefaultView;

            txtCarga.SelectAll();

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

public class frmPesquisa
{
    private frmPrincipal frmP;

    public frmPesquisa()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // Default constructor
    }

    public frmPesquisa(frmPrincipal frmP) : this()
    {
        this.frmP = frmP;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            this.Hide();

            // If we have a reference to the main form, then show it
            // and set the txtCarga text
            if (this.frmP != null && !this.frmP.IsDiposed)
            {
                frmP.Show();

                frmP.txtCarga.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                frmP.txtCarga.Focus();
                frmP.txtCarga.SelectAll();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use that method, the frmPrincipal will be closed and I want to keep it. That is no way?

Comment: If frmPrincipal is your main form, then you need to pass that reference into your popup form where datagridView1 is. So in public MyPopupForm(frmPrincipal frm) { ... this.frm = frm; }  That way you can always access the main form. I'm assuming that is your main form. I can't tell what you're doing without you posting all the relevant code (from all forms)

Comment: Where you create your popup form, you need to pass a reference to the first form "frmPesquisa frmP = new frmPesquisa(this);"   Then you can access it from the popup form

Comment: Just add the (this) parameter when you create your frmPesquisa. So change this line "frmPesquisa frmP = new frmPesquisa();" to "frmPesquisa frmP = new frmPesquisa(this);"   Then you'll also need to create a new constructor that takes the frmPrincipal parameter, and store it.

Comment: I did it, but it will create a new empty form without the content from my From2

Comment: See my new answer please

Comment: I already have it. But it will give an error on the "frmP.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["CargsCab"].DefaultView;", because of the reference

Comment: Now, both shows but after double clicking on row from Second Form it does not diplay the value on the TextBox from First Form

Comment: Yes in your doubleClick method it is updating the txtCarga value frmP.txtCarga.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();